stuck ether on smart contract
Is there any way to recover ether that is stuck in a smart contract? my ca.
0x1DA851535C587757d916C72Bdf0581cd2C38ea34

Probably, have a look at the sendETHToFee function which is called internally in _transfer. It's sending the full ether balance to the _taxWallet.

not working can you help me out

Apparently you could not run the enableTrading function (which is necessary to add liquidity and return the rest to you) because it has inside it the function to create the pool in uniswap (createPair).
The createPair function you have run on your own before and it created this 0xC65E00460550a87B513117D3Fc5b16318e4525d3 pair.
So when you try to run enableTrading, it fails because createPair has a require that says the pair must not have been created:
require(getPair[token0][token1] == address(0), 'UniswapV2: PAIR_EXISTS');

Without the possibility to run the enableTrading function the swapEnabled variable will never be true and unfortunately you will not have the possibility to enter the code block to run the sendETHToFee function which is the one that could get the eth out of the contract.

so i can't remove my fund?

Unfortunately it is not possible. I'm sorry I can't be of more help.
